# Do female goddesses of the trnity and other devis menstruate like human females?

Tags: goddess, menstruation

Are females of trinities menstrual like our human females?

Do the females of svargas like devis apsaras also produce menses like our.female mother and sisters? Please clear my doubts.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Manthānabhairava-tantra (Kumārikākhaṇḍa, chapter 3)](https://books.google.com/books?id=2DhazgEACAAJ), when the Goddess enters into her “fertile period” (ṛtukāla), she enters “into the Void which is the God’s couch”.

> And (I am) she who, during the Age of Strife (kaliyuga), descends (into this world) to liberate those who, frightened by the fear of the world of transmigration, desire liberation. I am Bhadrakālikā, formerly Dakṣa's daughter. My eyes (were) large, (I was) beautiful and married to Śambhu. (72-73)
>
> Given by Dakṣa (to lord Śiva) in order to bring about the emanation (of the universe) (sṛṣṭi) **I, the goddess, entered, during (my) fertile period (ṛtukāla), into the Void which is the god’s couch (vistara)**. I who am supreme bliss merged (into the expanse of the foundation) and assumed a body of bliss. (74-75ab)

[The word Ṛtukāla](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/ritukala) is explained as “the time of menstruation” or “the time that is most auspicious for sexual intercourse for a woman with her husband”. It consists of Ṛtu—‘menstruation’ and Kāla—‘time, period’.

According to the commentary on the above quote:

> **The goddess's menses, the most concrete sign of her gender marks her divine nature as it does that of her human counterpart**. Just as her body is bliss -an exalted transfigured body -her menses is her divine lunar energy. The fluidity of the menstral flow is the element Water and its vitality the cosmic Air, the breath of the universe. The epitome of the Tantric consort, she is the Mother of the Universe and her sphere of existence, the maṇḍala beyond the realms of death and decay. [...]

In a different part of the Tantra (Siddhakhaṇḍa, chapter 33), it is mentioned that the Goddess resides in the Circle of the Fertile Period:

> “[...] O god, supreme bliss is the Transmental (that abides) perpetually in the circle of the fertile period (ṛtumaṇḍala)”

Comment: do demi goddesses menstuates.too? wht is God couch.im not understanding .goddess becomes impure at menses days?plz tell

Comment: @HariHara I advise you to read the book and introduction part. The contents and technical terms are well-explained.

Comment: Can you plz provide the free readings online link to the manthanbhairav tantras book the current link opens a Google book which in not openable

Comment: @HariHara firstly what the heck is demigoddess term ? You mean devi is a demon who became goddess? Kindly correct that because, Demigod is an alien term. Secondly, yes Bhagwati Mahamaya does undergo periods. Just on 26th June her periods ended, "Ambubachi Parv". By impure he meant 'Apavitra'. Thus, the doors are closed after devi goes for menses. After nivritti happens, the doors are opened back for darshan